# C# WCF with IIS AAR cant process metadata

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, arr

I have a WCF Service hosted in IIS with BasicHttpBinding.

WCF is available through IIS and is routed to an internal HTTP Port with IIS Reverse Proxy (AAR).

When I want to embed the WCF in VisualStudio from my IIS then I can't add the Service Reference and get this error:

> The removeserver has returned an error: (415) Cannot process
>   the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml;
>   charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml;
>   charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   http://myServer/WebServices/WCF_mywebapi/Service.svc

However if I disable the IIS ARR Reverse proxy (and Host WCF directly on Port 80) then there is no Error.
Is there a problem with ReverseProxy handling my Request?
How can I debug them?

I have some other WebServices on WsHttpBinding and they work well on retriving metadata.

The web.config must be right because I can embed the wervice without active ARR.

I know that there are a few solutions to this error but none of them mention the AAR Module as source.

Can you help me?

Edit: Here whe web.config from WCF:

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89B483F429C47342"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfNamespaces.Service.svc">
        <endpoint address="Service.svc" bindingNamespace="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="" contract="WcfNamespaces.IService"/>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

My Server Config for Proxy:

```
  <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://127.0.0.1:1010/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
```

And I disabled svc ISAPI module for IIS Proxy Instance (because the're handled by IIS Instance on other port):

```
    <handlers>
  <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
  <remove name="svc-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
  <remove name="svc-Integrated-4.0" />
 </handlers>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: You can enable tracing in the WCF services config value and verify the correct methods are being called. Check out SvcTraceViewer.exe. Can you verify that your ARR set-up is not proxying calls to your other WsHttpBinding services? ( this would explain the soap vs text/xml discrepancy)

Comment: Can WCF Tracing trace metadata request? I cant call the service if i cant read metadata, so can tracing log Metadata requests? and my AAR setup works well on WsHttpBining metadata, but not well on BasicHttpMetatadata. Why there is a difference? The aar doesn't know about service entpoints because its defined by path.

Comment: Can you add your Web.Config to your original post? (as it is on the server)

Comment: Added Web.config for WCF

Comment: Couple things. 1. The address 'Service.svc' doesnt make sense as that's just the file used by WCF. (It's usually left blank) 2. The error message makes it seem like you are pulling the wsdl correctly, what are you typing into 'Add reference' and what is returned when you type that into a browser? 3. What are your proxy rules doing? They may be complicating things. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: 1. Thanks i will remove it 2. I type in the WCF Url and in Browser via HTTP it's reachable. In VS there is the giben error. But when I disable proxy and go directly to ServerPort on which WCF is, it works well, so the Source of error is the proxy. 3. In Current debug configuration all of my traffic will be proxy rewritten to my local Port (I added RewriteRule to my question)

Comment: So it's something with the rule. Check out the rules at the bottom of this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/configuring-application-request-routing-arr/creating-a-forward-proxy-using-application-request-routing . 127.0.0.1 is localhost? If IIS is on another machine, and you are trying to debug your service, shouldn't it be your IP?

Comment: Or just download the wsdl file and import it into VS, I think that might work

Comment: No, the AAR is used in this case to forward to other IIS Instances on same Machine with other ports. So multiple Applications are supported and I can maintain and put offline single Applications without setting the whole Server or ApplicationPool offline. So AAR is only used local. Sure I can import the WSDL but its much simpler to type in the Service Url. And I have to explain it to other people...

Comment: I don't have a solution yet...

Comment: You may want to follow this guide to trace what your proxy rules are actually doing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Comment: After debugging, I can say, that the AAR is forwarding the HTTP Reuests the right way. The error must be result of the web Service. Although the WCF Generation Client in VisualStudio has different behavior requesting AAR urls and non aar urls. But: This error occures too, if I call the working URL but in this case VS can ged rid of it.... Maybe I have to give up...